# Why can't I new a object in ES6?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning ES6, I wrote the test code like below:

```
// export.js:
class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log('teste5ty')
    }
}

class Test2 {
    constructor() {
        console.log('test2')
    }
}
export {Test, Test2}
export default Test
```

another export file code is below:

```
// test2.js
class Teste3 {
    construct() {
        console.log('heheheheh')
    }
}
export default Teste3
```

finally, test code as below:

```
import Test from './export'
import {Test2} from './export'
import Teste3 from './test2'

new Test()
new Test2()
new Teste3()
```

after transforming to es5 by Babel, I got the output like below:

```
teste5ty
test2
```

Apparently, Test3 is not instantiated, why this happens??

Comment: What is `testbundle`? How is it connected to `test2.js`? Provide the transpiled version of the main file as well.

Comment: @zerkms I revised it. Here is transpiled code:`'use strict';

var _export = require('./export');

var _export2 = _interopRequireDefault(_export);

var _test = require('./test2');

var _test2 = _interopRequireDefault(_test);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

new _export2.default();

new _export.Test2();

new _test2.default();`

Comment: Because there's no constructor code  for ... the teste. It's instantiated, you just don't know it.

Comment: Edit the question; don't try to wedge illegible code into comments.

Comment: @DaveNewton but, it it same with Test and Test2, how can this happen

Comment: No, it isn't the same.

Comment: alright, I got it....  what a low question....Thank  you two

Comment: Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is typo `construct`, not `constructor` for the `Teste3`